# Coded UI compiled DLLs in Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to use Coded UI compiled Dlls in Selenium project.
I Created on Class Library Project in Visual Studio where I created on class in this i write one simple method to draw highlight the "Save as window" like:

```
 namespace CreadeDll
  {
   public class Class1
  {

    public void ValidateSaveasWidnow()
    {
        WinWindow window = new WinWindow();
        window.SearchProperties.Add(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlType, "Window");
        window.SearchProperties.Add(WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name, "Save Print Output As"); 
        window.DrawHighlight();
    }
}
```

}

After Build the application, i added this DLL in my selenium (C#, which is different project) project through reference.

```
 namespace  SeleniumProj
 {
    [TestFixture] 
  public  class TestDll
   {

    [Test]
    public void gets()
    {             
        CreadeDll.Class1 c = new CreadeDll.Class1();
         c.ValidateSaveasWidnow();            
    }
}
```

}

But the problem here is i am unable to Build. When i try to run it is giving message like "There were build errors"

Comment: What is it you expect to get from CodedUI that you can't already get from just Selenium? Also... we're going to need something a LOT more specific than "There were build errors".

Comment: Hi Jeff, thank you for response. In selenium we are unable to handle the window forms, so i am trying to handle those scenarios from coded UI.

Comment: What's the issue you are having with window forms? I don't think there's anything that CodedUI can do that Selenium can't.

Comment: yes using third party tools we can handle window forms in selenium like 'Autoit', but i am trying to use the coded UI stuff in selenium is it possible?

Comment: Please add build error detail?

Answer (score 0):

Coded UI is available only in enterprise license of Visual Studio. Also VS 2019 will be the last version of Visual Studio that contains the Coded UI test functionality as Microsoft is deprecating the coded UI from later version onward. For more detail on this please follow this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/changes-to-coded-ui-test-in-visual-studio-2019/) .

I would suggest to go for appium Winappdriver to solve your windows UI control problem. 
You can get appium winappdiver from this link : https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver

To learn more about WInappdriver you can refer the below links:

- [Winappdriver 8 minutes overview with demos](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Connect/2016/202)
- [C# demo with calculator sample walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAJVpvaEchY)